# Display and update data column of type time in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sql, datatable

I have an sql server data table with a column of type time(0). I need to display columns of this table on a sharepoint page, including the time-column. Users must be able to read and update rows.
What is the easiest way to accomplish this? I tried to create an external content type and external list, but the list does not support System.TimeSpan, which is the equivalent to the time-column in .Net.

At the moment I see no better way than building the operations from scratch with a custom web part.